# Create Dynamically series of TDBChart in delphi: Data not changing

Tags: delphi, charts

I have used following code to create Dynamically series of TDBChart. I used MS-Access and TADOQuery component. CODE on BUTTON Click Event.

```
var
qryData: TADOQuery;
intCnt: integer;
strlstField: TStringList;

begin
strlstField := TStringList.Create();
qryData := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
qryData.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=' + ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'data.mdb';
qryData.SQL.Add('SELECT dept_name,2005 as [2005],2006 as [2006],2007 as [2007],'+
               '2008 as [2008],2009 as [2009],2010 as [2010], 2011 as [2211] FROM SALES');
qryData.Active := True;

DBChart1.Title.Text.Clear;
DBChart1.Title.Text.Add('Department Wise Sales Report');
DBChart1.Title.Font.Size := 14;
DBChart1.LeftAxis.Title.Font.Size := 12;   
DBChart1.LeftAxis.Title.Caption := 'Sales in Rs.';
DBChart1.BottomAxis.Title.Font.Size := 12;
DBChart1.BottomAxis.Title.Caption := 'Department Name';

//Charting Series
   //To Remove Old Series
for intCnt := DBChart1.SeriesCount -1 downto 0 do
   DBChart1.Series[intCnt].Free;
   //To Add New Series
for intCnt := 1 to qryData.FieldCount - 1 do begin
   strlstField.Add(qryData.FieldList[intCnt].FieldName);
   DBChart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries.Create(nil));
end;
   //To set source for Series
for intCnt:= 0 to DBChart1.SeriesCount -1 do begin
   with  DBChart1 do begin
      Series[intCnt].Clear;
      Series[intCnt].Title := strlstField[intCnt];
      Series[intCnt].ParentChart := DBChart1;
      Series[intCnt].DataSource := qryData;
      Series[intCnt].XLabelsSource := 'dept_name';
      Series[intCnt].YValues.ValueSource := strlstField[intCnt];
   end;
end;
```

PROBLEM: When i change data in DATABASE and Re-run the application chart remain same. No reflection done in chart series. Had any mistake in Above Code?
[image]

Another Problem is that in the picture, series are at 2000 value, but i have add all value above 20,000 in the DATABASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELECT statement is passing integers, not field names, which is why they are all around 2,000 - because that is the value of the year as an integer.

Are your fields actually called `2005` etc? If so, you need to bracket the field names so they are treated like field names and not like integers:

```
qryData.SQL.Add('SELECT dept_name, [2005] as [2005], [2006] as [2006], [2007] as [2007], ' +
    '[2008] as [2008], [2009] as [2009], [2010] as [2010], [2011] as [2011] FROM SALES');
```

Note also that you are aliasing `2011` incorrectly as `2211` (fixed in mine above).

Comment: Yes, but the problem you are having is that "2005 as [A]" passes the literal integer value 2005 as a column called "A", not the value of a field called "2005". To have SQL treat it as field name you need to surround the field name (not the alias like you are doing) with square brackets: "[2005] as A". You just have the brackets around the wrong part.

Comment: I used alias 2011 as 2211 for **check** the reflection in chart. And i change Filed name as string. therefore having the problem.     ' qryData.SQL.Add('SELECT dept_name,2005 as [a],2006 as [b],2007 as [c],'+ '2008 as [d],2009 as [e],2010 as [f], 2011 as [g] FROM SALES');'